# Porting Angular app with Cordova also using Bower

Tags: angularjs

I've installed the iOS and Android build tools for Cordova and after I have run `cordova build` in my main directory I get an empty www folder. My Angular source is normally managed by bower, should I manually copy them into the source directory for the new build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cordova Documentation for Cordova Build Command](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Cordova%20Command-line%20Interface_build_the_app)

The `cordova prepare` step (which should run when you use `cordova build`), copies files from your project-wide www/ folder, and then compiles the project. When I use grunt or gulp with my ionic/cordova project, I build my javascript/html project into the main www/ folder before running `cordova build`, which would include copying/concatenating bower dependencies.